# How to iterate over all Int32s in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Any idea why my loop

`for(int i = Int32.MinValue; i <= Int32.MaxValue; ++i)`

isn't terminating? Should not this be the way to iterate over all `int`s?

Comment: Look at the result of `int.MaxValue + 1` and see if that' doesn't answer your question.

Comment: What are you doing in the for loop? There are 2,147,483,648 numbers in the range of a 32 bit number, could it be that doing whatever you are doing that many times is taking a very long time?

Comment: [-2,147,483,648 - 2,147,483,648] is more than that many numbers @Kevin lol

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of 0 - Int32.MaxValue, but he is going from Int32.MinValue to Int32 MaxValue.

Comment: As long as `i` is a 32 bit integer, it will always be `<= Int32.MaxValue` no matter what its bits are set to.  try `long long i`

Comment: I have made the same mistake

Comment: Use `long i` or `int i = int.MaxValue; do { Console.WriteLine(++i); } while(i < int.MaxValue);`.

Comment: I updated my answer marked as a duplicate with another option (`do...while` loop)